# JEE project with Keycloak: keep getting invalid redirect URI error

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, keycloak

I’m working on a JEE project, implementing REST APIs with JAX-RS. I’m using Wildfly v21 as my application server, while my project is running on **http://localhost:8081** (changed to get a different port from Keycloak which is running on **http://localhost:8080**) . I’ve configurated it with Keycloak using the JBoss EAP/WildFly adapter, and it seems well configurated.

**web.xml:**

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>auth_prototype</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>auth-proto-realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

**keycloak.json:**

```
{
  "realm": "auth-proto-realm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "auth-proto-client",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "secret"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

The issue is whatever URI I put in Valid Redirect URIs I keep getting the error invalid redirect URIs or it keeps loading the page without success:

[image]

[image]

I’ve tried everything but nothing seems to work, are my configurations ok?
Thanks a lot

[EDIT]
After launching Keyloak with .standalone.bat, I see this:

```
13:50:51,713 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
    13:50:51,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\keycloak-13.0.1\standalone\deployments
    13:50:51,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
    13:50:52,023 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
    13:50:52,025 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    13:50:53,139 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
```

So I've got an HTTP listener also on 8443, that's why maybe it's redirecting to 8444?

Comment: Share the full URL where you are seeing invalid redirect uri error

Comment: This is the URL I get:    http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/auth-proto-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=auth-proto-client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8444%2Fauth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT%2Fapi%2Fusers&state=838ce3d8-4291-43a0-b9cb-24affa27220f&login=true&scope=openid

Answer (score 1):

According to URI shared, you are redirecting your request to `https://localhost:8444/auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/users` and According to the screenshot shared, you are setting Valid Redirect URIs as `http://localhost:8081/auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/users` in client configuration of keycloak which is incorrect.

If you are running your app on 8444, then you should set Valid Redirect URIs from keycloak admin console as `https://localhost:8444/auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT/*` (Not including `/api/users/`, as I'm assuming you want to make any child pages as valid redirect URIs)

Comment: My app is actually running on 8081, since I changed the port( -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1) in Intellij to not have my app and keycloak running on same port. But from what I see launching Keycloak I have HTTP listener also on 8443. (EDIT in question, can't add it here).

Comment: @this.jind On which port is your app runnnig? If its running on 8081, why is the keycloak/app redirect you to 8444? (I am refering to redirect_uri=https://localhost:8444/auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/users in the url shared by you)

Comment: My app(a JEE project) is running on 8081, I don't understand why Keycloak is redirecting me to 8444. I'm really not finding any solutions.

Comment: I believe that your application server converting your http requests to https request because of which you are getting redirected to 8443 port. Add HTTPS URL in your Valid Redirect URIs

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what Widlfly is doing, for now I solved it adding my https URL in the Valid Redirect URIs. Thanks a lot!